# ssh into Android to send WOL packet

Tags: android, ssh, wake-on-lan

I want to WakeOnLAN my NAS server remotely, but my router blocks WOL packets. I thought I could circumvent this by ssh'ing into our androidTV box, and sending a WOL packet from there on the LAN.
I can ssh into the androidTV, but can't send the WOL packet.
Is it possible to run a graphical ssh session to the androidTV and then use one of the WOL apps in the Play Store?
Or is there any way I can use a WakeOnLan application from terminal?

Comment: Have you found a solution? If so,  please answer your question! I want to do the same thing! Thx

Comment: @nelsonec87 I ended up using a Raspberry Pi running XMBC instead of the Android box. That works quite well.

Comment: I tried to set up an SSH server on my TV Box and tried "busybox ether-wake MAC" but not wake up the device. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the solution as I was trying to achieve the same thing.

**Problem:** 
I need to remotely power on my server at home using Wake on Lan (WoL) command. For WoL to work reliably, a PC within the LAN needs to be used to send the WoL command, and NOT a remote PC. I don't completely understand the reason why, but it has something to do with the router clearing the ARP table cache after a device is powered off. In our case, the server that is switched off but we want to remotely turn it on. For more details read here: https://serverfault.com/questions/161560/how-to-get-wake-on-lan-working/349783#349783

**Solution** 
You can have a device within the LAN which can send the WoL command to the powered off server. One way to do this is by having a rooted Android device which is running a SSH server. You can remotely login to the Android device using SSH and then send the WoL command.

**Steps I used**

1. Root an Android device and ensure you have [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) installed
2. Install a SSH server on the Android. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9905/is-there-some-ssh-server-for-android. I used SSHDroid.
3. Remotely login to your Android device using SSH. Ex: `ssh -p 2222 root@xxx.xxx.x.xxx`
4. Send the WoL command using `ether-wake -b -i wlan0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`. Reference: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2495288
5. Steps 3 and 4 can be combined in one go using this example: `ssh -p 2222 root@xxx.xxx.x.xxx "su -c ether-wake -b -i wlan0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"`

**Note:**

- The above steps may differ based on the type of device. The update steps are for an Android device, but the same principle can be used on non-Android devices.
- On Android you can NOT use the [`wakeonlan` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wol). You have to use [`ether-wake` command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ether-wake). This is because BusyBox doesn't install `wakeonlan`.
- You must have sudo or root privileges to issue the `ether-wake` command